# Removing class in HTML is not capturing correct CSS styling

Tags: css

Using Bootstrap as my default CSS, I also created a custom .css file I made that creates a loading screen when my webpage is processing the information. Basically, my loading screen is hiding in the background and I use javascript to bring it to the front for any triggers.

Here is the CSS code:

```
#loading-page.loading {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#loading-page.loading #loading-page-icon {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #3498db;
  z-index: 1001;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

#loading-page.loading #loading-page-icon:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #e74c3c;
  -webkit-animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
}

#loading-page.loading #loading-page-icon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #f9c922;
  -webkit-animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg)
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg)
  }
}

#loading-page.loading .loading-curtain {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 51%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #5c5c5c;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#loading-page.loading .loading-curtain.section-left {
  left: 0;
}

#loading-page.loading .loading-curtain.section-right {
  right: 0;
}


/* Once the page loads */

#loading-page:not(.loading) {
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
  transform: translateY(-100%) -webkit-transition: all 0.3s 1s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s 1s ease-out;
}

#loading-page:not(.loading) #loading-page-icon {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

#loading-page:not(.loading) .loading-curtain.section-left {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  transition: all 0.7s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
}

#loading-page:not(.loading) .loading-curtain.section-right {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  transition: all 0.7s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
}
```

Here is my HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="loading-page">
      <div id="loading-page-icon"></div>
      <div class="loading-curtain section-left"></div>
      <div class="loading-curtain section-right"></div>
    </div>

   ...[other html code]
</body>
```

And then here is my Javascript I use to remove the class on my div#loading-page

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /*
        When a page fully loads, remove the .loading class

    */

    $('#loading-page')
        .removeClass('loading')
})

$(document).on(
    "submit", 
    [
        'form.search',
    ], 
    function() {
        /*
            Event Listener- anytime the search form is submitted, display the 
            loading screen.

        */

            $('#loading-page')
                .addClass('loading')
})
```

The only problem I have with my CSS code is for some reason, my transition animation will not work (where you see 'Once the page loads' comment in .css) - as if I performed a .hide() on #loading-page than removing the class. I'm pretty sure the CSS is getting ignored. I even tried to force the styling by trying to use the :not('loading') operator. Besides the animation not working, the loading screen does pop up and then goes away once the document is ready as expected. Any help why my CSS is getting ignored?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Adding and removing `.loading` toggles the `visibility` property - which can't be transitioned.  Something is either hidden or not.  If you want to fade in the element, use `opacity`, and possibly `pointer-events` so the invisible-but-still present element doesn't capture click events.